# Getting `Unable to configure` release! with Distillery

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, distillery

I'm trying to do a Distillery release and getting the message `Unable to configure release!` when running `_build/dev/rel/acompanhante/bin/acompanhante foreground`.

The release config module for distillery the is used:

```
...

alias Distillery.Releases.Config.Providers.Elixir, as: RuntimeConfig

environment :dev do
  set dev_mode: true
  set include_erts: false
  set cookie: :"gOjXA4x?QPjR0c*$/yIq9{S&/s]p}}K?gNz_$O4Uf6I[Ql/L(g7*:st70YPY={?$"
end

environment :prod do
  set include_erts: true
  set include_src: false
  set cookie: :"OzWR<VV9?T=2o=F@9KxRTTm|CIGO/BoT9p_^D/QN6CY3}v<4?;yRjhR(v^nz1fvR"
  set vm_args: "rel/vm.args"
end

release :acompanhante do
  set config_providers: [{RuntimeConfig, ["${RELEASE_ROOT_DIR}/etc/config.exs"]}]
  set overlays: [{:copy, "config/releases.exs", "etc/config.exs"}]
  set version: current_version(:acompanhante)
  set applications: [
    :runtime_tools,
    :logger
  ]
end
```

The module for config the runtime that is used:

```
import Config

...

config :acompanhante, Acompanhante.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  ssl: true,
  url: database_url,
  pool_size: String.to_integer(System.get_env("POOL_SIZE") || "10")

config :acompanhante, AcompanhanteWeb.Endpoint,
  http: [
    port: String.to_integer(System.get_env("PORT") || "4000"),
    transport_options: [socket_opts: [:inet6]]
  ],
  secret_key_base: secret_key_base,
  code_reloader: false
```

What I'm doing wrong to build the appup?

Comment: Is there a reason to use Distillery?  Do you just want to build a release somehow?

Comment: I believe with distillery I can manage the cycle of a release more smoothly with commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is needed to configure the runtime:

```
release :acompanhante do
  set config_providers: [{RuntimeConfig, ["${RELEASE_ROOT_DIR}/etc/runtime.exs"]}]
  set overlays: [{:copy, "config/releases.exs", "etc/runtime.exs"}]
  ...
end
```